# Position-time graph of two cars is given

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

So this was a test question, I answered that both cars have the same acceleration. Since the graphs for A and B both are straight lines, therefore, the acceleration of both must be zero. But the answer given to us was that both are moving with same velocity.

[image]

These graphs are not always to scale, so I thought that the d option would be more appropriate than c. The beginning of the test says to mark the most appropriate answer.

Comment: If they are really are straight lines, then they have the same acceleration: zero. If they really are *parallel* lines, then their velocities are the same. (1) and (2) are definitely wrong if the lines are parallel, but if *not*, then it's hard to tell from the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question, it seems to me that both c and d could be answer choices because the velocity is the same because it can be seen that the slope of the displacement-time graph is increasing at the same rate as the other one, and it is hard to check whether the slopes are exactly the same or slightly off, and since we don't have any numbers, it could be subjective. This is because, the velocity is the slope of position vs time, and acceleration is the slope of the slope, which can be easily seen by looking at concavity.

However, from the looks of it, it seems that the answer is c, but d also seems to work.

Because again, like you said they are straight lines and so that means there is  no concavity, which just means that the rate of change of velocity is zero and this is true for both, so their accelerations are also zero.

So it is possible that the test question's answer key answer might be wrong, because it would be that they have both the same velocity and acceleration.

In terms of picking the best answer, I would say that they are both equally valid options, so I guess it could be (3) or (4). It is possible that the answer choice was (3) because that is the statement that can kind of be made quickly just by looking at the graph instead of trying to analyze concavity so that might explain why the answer key had (3) as the answer and not (4).